# Как работать с access token android retrofit?

Tags: android, get, retrofit

У в приложении во время входа по логину и паролю мне присваивается два токена которые я так понял потом нужны для дальнейшей работы. У меня есть интерфейс для get запроса:

```
    Call<MessageAnswer> getInMess(@Query("count") Integer method);
```

и дальше у меня выводит ошибку с сервера что у меня неверный параметр (invalid_parameter_value) я так понял что мне все-таки нужно как-то извлекать из json ответа токен, но я так думаю что это костыльно вставлять вручную)) так вот как мне извлечь именно access token из моего предыдущего удачного ответа. И дальше у меня самый главный вопрос: как инициализировать мой интерфейс в моем главном классе. Я сейчас пробую так:

```
APIService mAPIService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
        mAPIService.getInMess(a).enqueue(new Callback<MessageAnswer>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MessageAnswer> call, Response<MessageAnswer> response) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MessageAnswer> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

но мне не понятно как инициализировать переменную которая объявлена в интерфейсе?? Буду очень благодарен за оказанную помощь и полезные ответы, так как это единственное что я не могу понять в данном get запросе.

Comment: Скорее проблема в этом `?type=TYPE`. Попробуйте убрать и сделать так: `(@Query("type") int type, @Query("offset") int offset). Для первой порции вызывать `getInMess(0, 0)`.

Comment: @woesss у меня к вам вопрос, что за 0,0 стоит в значении функции?

Comment: Ошибка 500 значит, что сервер сломался на Вашем запросе ))) или вообще. Возможно, запрос всё-таки не правильный, но на бэкэнде не предусмотрели нужную проверку. Попробуйте без параметра `offset`. И неплохо бы потестить запрос в постмане или тому подобном, чтоб не пересобирать 100500 раз проект.

Comment: `0,0` - это `query` параметры `type` и `offset`, которые указаны у Вас [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/859454/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-get-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-retrofit-android) (URL Params)

Comment: та я пытался разобраться с postman но так и не получилось то я уже в приложении пробую, я вот вместо 0,0 вставил 1,1 и вставил access token и запрос прошел нормально, но теперь нужно как-то вставлять токен в процессе работы

Comment: Если Вы уже делали `authenticator` - то в гайде есть пример как раз с `bearer`: https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#handling-authentication

Comment: ну я если правильно понял, нужно ответ с сервера, если он удачный, разбирать построчно, и когда находим token мы его вытаскиваем и вставляем в interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Токен нужно при получении записать в переменную, и если он долговременный можно сохранить в `SharedPreferenses` или куда удобнее.
Добавлять его в заголовок есть несколько способов, покажу что попроще:

```
// content-type не нужен - мы на сервер не передаём json
@GET("/v1/message/list")
Call<MessageAnswer> getInMess(@Query("type") int type, @Query("offset") int offset, @Header("Authorization") String token);
```

При каждом вызове метода нужно будет последним параметром вставлять токен.